# $f(r) \leq \int_r^{r+1} f(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Suppose $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ is continuous (uniformly, if you want) and that $\int_0^{\infty} f(t)~\mathrm{d}t < \infty$. Is the following true?
$$
f(r) \leq \int_r^{r+1} f(t)~\mathrm{d}t
$$
This seems obviously true to me since $f$ is nonnegative, but I haven't been able to prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is decreasing on $[r,r+1]$ then $f(r) > f(t)$ for $r < t \le r+1$, which yields:

$f(r) = \displaystyle\int_{r}^{r+1}f(r)\,dt > \int_{r}^{r+1}f(t)\,dt$.

So, the inequality is false for any decreasing function, such as $f(t) = \dfrac{1}{(1+t)^2}$

Comment: Nice! Would the statement be true if, instead of $r+1$ as the upper limit of integration, we had $+\infty$?

Comment: No, try $f(t) = e^{-at}$ for $a > 1$.

Comment: Good call. Thanks for your input!